# Triggering alerts with validate-need in Shiny?

Tags: html, r, shiny

I am having difficulty triggering an alert in a Shiny app that I have created. The app itself is very simple, and displays one slider with numbers and a line plot. However, I would like for an alert to be triggered whenever the slider is set to a value above 5. Here is the code:

UI

```
library(shiny)
library(shinythemes)
library(shinyBS)

shinyUI(fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("superhero"),
              tags$head(
                tags$style(HTML("
  .shiny-output-error-validation {
    color: green;
  }
"))
              ),

sidebarLayout(
sidebarPanel(
  sliderInput("samplestat",
              "Value:",
              min = 1,
              max = 10,
              value = 1)
),

    mainPanel(
  h3("Graph", style = "font-family: 'Jura'; color: blue; font-size: 32px;"),
  HTML("<p>Graph</p>"),
  plotOutput("LinePlot")
)
)
))
```

SERVER

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(scales)

samplestat <- function(input) {
if (input > 5) {
"Choose another value. samplestat must be below 5!"
} else if (input < 4) {
FALSE
} else {
NULL
}
}

shinyServer(function(input, output) {

data <- reactive({
validate(
  need(input$data != "", "Please select a value below 5")
)
get(input$data)
})

output$LinePlot <- renderPlot({

n=1:10
samplestat <- seq(min(n), max(n), length.out = input$samplestat)

plot(samplestat, type = "o", col = 'blue', border = 'white', xlab="X Axis", ylab ="Y Axis")
}

)

})
```

When I run this code, the line and slider displays, but I do not get any alert when I slide the slider to a value above 5. I am not sure if I am possibly using validate-need incorrectly, or whether I have overlooked something else.

Comment: `input$data` isn't your input, should be `input$samplestat`, and you want to check if it's over 5 right? not if it's equal to `""`. There's a lot here that needs fixing, but the important thing is that you shouldn't be checking `input` directly, and `input$data` is never defined.

Comment: @Shape: Yes, I have replaced all instances of ```input$data``` with ```input$samplestat```, and have inputted: ```data <- reactive({
  validate(
    need(input$samplestat > 5)```. However, the code is simply showing the graph plot and not an alert when samplestat is above 5.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should place `validate(...)` insider `renderPlot({...})`. That is, your `server.R` should be something like:

```
function(input, output) {
  output$LinePlot <- renderPlot({
    validate(
      need(input$samplestat <= 5, "Please select a value below 5")
    )
    n <- 1:10
    samplestat <- seq(min(n), max(n), length.out = input$samplestat)
    plot(samplestat, type = "o", col = 'blue', 
      fg = 'white', xlab= "X Axis", ylab = "Y Axis")
  })
}
```

which produces this output:
[image]

---

Note that there should be no problem with wrapping your validation code in a reactive function.  Suppose your function to test for a condition is

```
validate_samplestat <- function(input) {
  if (input > 5) {
    "Choose another value. samplestat must be below 5!"
  } else {
    NULL
  }
}
```

You can wrap this in `reactive` in your main server function, and place the reactive function in your output rendering function.  The main thing is to place the bit of code that calls `validate` *in your output rendering function*:

```
function(input, output) {
  v <- reactive({
    validate(validate_samplestat(input$samplestat))
  })

  output$LinePlot <- renderPlot({
    v() # <--- validate here
    n <- 1:10
    samplestat <- seq(min(n), max(n), length.out = input$samplestat)
    plot(samplestat, type = "o", col = 'blue', 
      fg = 'white', xlab= "X Axis", ylab = "Y Axis")
  })
}
```

Comment: Thank you, that works. The issue may have been using the validate and need functions under a data <- reactive function. Thanks once again.